# I can't start node.js on hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, hosting, firebase-admin

I am trying to install my node.js server in hosting. The server running on Windows but not work in hosting.

**RUN NPM INSTALL ERRROR**

```
An error occured during installation of modules. The operation was performed, but check availability of application has failed. Web application responds, but its return code "500 Internal Server Error" or content type before operation "text/html; charset=UTF-8" doesn't equal to contet type after operation "text/html; charset=UTF-8".
```

**START SERVER ERROR**

```
Error: error:02016002:system library:stat:No such file or directory
        at Sign.sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:86:29)
        at Object.sign (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/score/12/lib/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/node_modules/jwa/index.js:152:45)
        at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/score/12/lib/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:32:24)
        at Object.module.exports [as sign] (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/score/12/lib/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:186:16)
        at ServiceAccountCredential.createAuthJwt_ (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/score/12/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:101:20)
        at ServiceAccountCredential.getAccessToken (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/score/12/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:75:26)
        at FirebaseAppInternals.getToken (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/score/12/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:64:73)
        at AuthTokenProvider.getToken (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/score/12/lib/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:9231:27)
        at PersistentConnection.establishConnection_ (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/score/12/lib/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12133:18)
        at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/maksoboi/nodevenv/score/12/lib/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12035:19) {
      opensslErrorStack: [
        'error:0E07606D:configuration file routines:module_run:module initialization error',
        'error:0E07B075:configuration file routines:ssl_module_init:ssl command section empty'
      ],
      library: 'system library',
      function: 'stat',
      reason: 'No such file or directory',
      code: 'ERR_OSSL_SYS_NO_SUCH_FILE_OR_DIRECTORY'
    }
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/maksoboi/.npm/_logs/2020-01-27T09_03_28_330Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to stop the application before running NPM install. That should fix it

Comment: perfect. so simple, yet not immediately obvious

Comment: hey guys, can you take a look at this post of mine? It has an error similar to this one and I can't seem to fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962661/error3407b06fkdf-routineskdf-scrypt-derivemissing-salt-while-logging-into

Comment: perfect and also change node version

Comment: This works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

[image: You need to stop the application like]

Then go back to try npm install or

Locate your terminal you cpanel and install the package.json file directly from your terminal.